# how to access properties across classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

I want to have two classes interact each other, but the class interaction is not as I expected. How to fix it?

```
class InstanceActions {

 static handleInstanceAction() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

class main {
  constructor() {
    InstanceActions.handleInstanceAction(); // expected main, but undefined
  }
}

new main();
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use an arrow function like that, use `static handleInstanceAction() { console.log(this); }`. But note that *this* is set by the call, so will be *InstanceActions* because you're just using it like a plain (base) object for the call.

Comment: What do you mean by *"expected main"*? If you did `InstanceActions.handleInstanceAction.call(this)` then you'd get all properties of `main` (though you don't have any in your example so it'd just be `{}` in this case).

Comment: @TylerRoper Have you ever tried? I got 'call' of undefined error

Comment: @WeijingJayLin See here: https://jsfiddle.net/0jw6qgn5/  - It seems to work fine once the syntax error in your static method is tidied up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as written throws a syntax error, the syntax for a static method is:

```
static methodName () {
  methodBody
}
```

So your code should be:

```js
class InstanceActions {

  static handleInstanceAction() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

class main {
  constructor() {
    InstanceActions.handleInstanceAction(); // expected main, but undefined
  }
}

new main();
```

The result is:

```
class InstanceActions {

  static handleInstanceAction() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

because you're using calling *handleInstanceAction* as a  method of *InstanceActions*, so it's being treated as a plain object.

In javascript, *this* is controlled by the call (except for arrow functions).

Comment: Your code is actually return class instance action, but I actually want to return main; what can I do? My top goal is actually be able to access the parent class data from the child.

Comment: *InstanceActions* and *main* have no relationship at all, they are not "parent" and "child". They are both functions defined using the "class" syntax that can (almost identically) be declared using ECMAScript ed 3 function syntax without "class".

Comment: I think I might use the wrong term, what I should call each other if class A use class B?

Comment: oh, I see, it should be container (super) and component (sub) class